# Docker image runs standalone but fails under EKS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-eks

I have a docker image based on python, here relevant lines:

```
RUN python -m venv .testenv
RUN . .testenv/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip

RUN . .testenv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Image created successfully and runs on the local machine and in AWS EC2 machine (architecture is Linux/x86_64)

But when deployed on EKS container fails with the exception:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /root/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping tokenizers/punkt.zip.
[nltk_data] Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger to
[nltk_data]     /root/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger.zip.
./run-as-api.sh: line 5:     8 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) python main.py
```

One of the dependicied uses nltk

Some probable causes that were rejected:

- The EKS machine is of the right architecture (linux/x86_64)
- The nltk data is successfully downloaded and unzipped - so permissions are ok
- The machine and pod have enough local disk for downloaded nltk data
- The pod has no defined limits on CPU/memory
- There are no liveness/readiness probes defined in the pod

Again the image itself is fine as it works perfectly standalone under docker on EC2 machine of the same kind as EKS node

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Are those .aienv and .testenv paths? Which is to say, your Dockerfile looks like you create the .aienv venv but try to source the .testenv path.

Comment: sorry, its typing mistake, docker file uses consistent names